# Unable to assign value to a textbox property in c#

Tags: c#, .net, reporting-services

```
string stEx = cr.Text;
txtbox.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0].Value.Expression = stEx;
```

I have a value in stEx and I need to assign it to `

```
txtbox.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0].Value.Expression
```

Now I am getting the below error.

```
Cannot modify the return value of TextRun.Value because it is not a variable
```

Really appreciate any suggestions on this.

Comment: What is txtBox? Doesn't look like the usual asp.net textbox control

Comment: @Darren, it is not, this is Reporting Services. I retagged

Comment: @Darren - Andrei is correct.

Comment: @Andrei -I saw the post you tagged and couldn't get it. Could you pls provide your insights?

Comment: @vicky, what exactly is not clear? `Value` is of struct type, which is value type. You cannot change property of value type like that. Instead create a new instance of assign the whole `Value` with it.